# Execute Java method from SoapUI project

Tags: java, groovy, jar, soapui, maven-plugin

I have a `Java` [project](https://github.com/esig/dss/tree/master/dss-token/src/test/java/eu/europa/esig/dss/token) and a test class with a method, which should be executed from a `Groovy` script in `SoapUI`.
Method to be executed:

```
@Test
public void testPkcs12() throws IOException {
    try (Pkcs12SignatureToken signatureToken = new Pkcs12SignatureToken("src/test/resources/user_a_rsa.p12",
            new PasswordProtection("password".toCharArray()))) {
        assertNotNull(signatureToken);

        List<DSSPrivateKeyEntry> keys = signatureToken.getKeys();
        assertFalse(keys.isEmpty());

        KSPrivateKeyEntry dssPrivateKeyEntry = (KSPrivateKeyEntry) keys.get(0);
        assertNotNull(dssPrivateKeyEntry);
        assertNotNull(dssPrivateKeyEntry.getAlias());

        DSSPrivateKeyEntry entry = signatureToken.getKey(dssPrivateKeyEntry.getAlias(), new PasswordProtection("password".toCharArray()));
        assertNotNull(entry);
        assertNotNull(entry.getCertificate());
        assertNotNull(entry.getCertificateChain());
        assertNotNull(entry.getEncryptionAlgorithm());

        ToBeSigned toBeSigned = new ToBeSigned("Hello world".getBytes("UTF-8"));
        SignatureValue signValue = signatureToken.sign(toBeSigned, DigestAlgorithm.SHA256, entry);
        assertNotNull(signValue);
        assertNotNull(signValue.getAlgorithm());
        assertNotNull(signValue.getValue());

  System.out.println(DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(signValue.getValue()));
    }
}
```

I generated `jar` file with following plugin.

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.1</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <goals>
          <goal>test-jar</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

I call it in `SoapUI`:

```
import eu.europa.esig.dss.token.Pkcs12SignatureTokenTest;
log.info Pkcs12SignatureTokenTest.testPkcs12();
```

I get following error message:

> groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: static
>   eu.europa.esig.dss.token.Pkcs12SignatureTokenTest.testPkcs12() is
>   applicable for argument types: () values: [] Possible solutions:
>   testPkcs12() error at line: 3

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to call `testPkcs12` as if it were static but it's obviously not. Just try:

```
import eu.europa.esig.dss.token.Pkcs12SignatureTokenTest
new Pkcs12SignatureTokenTest().testPkcs12()
```

Comment: I got error message in this case too:
`org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed: Script6.groovy: 3: unable to resolve class Pkcs12SignatureTokenTest.testPkcs12 @ line 3, column 1. new Pkcs12SignatureTokenTest.testPkcs12() ^`

Comment: @plaidshirt you haven't removed `import eu.europa.esig.dss.token.Pkcs12SignatureTokenTest`, have you? And I also forgot `()` while calling the constructor in my answer (now fixed). Please use `new Pkcs12SignatureTokenTest().testPkcs12()`

Comment: I still get NoClassDefFoundError. Class in source: https://github.com/esig/dss/blob/master/dss-token/src/test/java/eu/europa/esig/dss/token/Pkcs12SignatureTokenTest.java

Comment: Have you put the JAR file in one of the folders that SoapUI scans on start up?  You could try restarting SoapUI to see if it picks it up.

Comment: @plaidshirt I assume that now the method in subject is called correctly but fails inside itself due to some other class not found. It would be helpful to see the stack trace’s part where the `NoClassDefFoundError` happens to locate the line of code with not found class. Looks like some other jars are missing in your run

Comment: I copied all the generated jars to /bin/ext folder. Error is about SignatureTokenConnection class. Should I generate jar with other method?

Comment: @plaidshirt I'm not a user of mentioned library. All I can say is that in their GitHub repo, I can easily figure out which jar the class `SignatureTokenConnection` belongs to. The jar can be found at their Nexus repo mentioned in the doc. But I'm not sure whether adding of just that single jar will solve the issue because there might be other transitive dependencies. The only ways to know for sure is to find it in the doc (which I don't see at first glance) or clone the repo and run `Pkcs12SignatureTokenTest` through maven with `-X` option to see the necessary classpath (jars)

Comment: @plaidshirt and to be honest I find it a bit strange that you are trying to run some unit test in soapui which is by definition is not supposed to used this way

Comment: @DmitryKhamitov : It would be a temporary solution, but I just looking for a solution which is working in all cases.